# Is a quasi-finite endomorphism of affine $n$-space finite?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb A^n$ be the affine space over $\mathbb C$ and let $f:\mathbb A^n\rightarrow \mathbb A^n$ be a quasi-finite morphism. In particular it is dominant.

> Is $f$ necessarily a finite morphism?

Comment: If this were true, the notorius Jacobian problem would be solved!

Comment: @Mohan: How do you see that? f is not an isomorphism!

Comment: Jacobian condition implies the map is quasi-finite. If it is finite, the map is proper and thus a covering. But, $\mathbb{C}^n$ is simply connected and thus the covering must be trivial.

Comment: But how do you see that it is unramified?

Comment: Jacobian condition is precisely saying that the map is unramified.

Answer (score 2):

If it is finite, then it is surjective. (Indeed, finite morphisms are proper.)

Thus, it suffices to exhibit a quasi-finite non-surjective endomorphism. Let $f:\mathbb{A}^2\to \mathbb{A}^2$ be given by $(x,y)\mapsto (g(x,y),h(x,y))$. Composing with an automorphism if necessary, $f$ is non-surjective if and only if $Z(g)\cap Z(h) =\emptyset$. (This means that the origin is not in the image.)

So, how about $g= x+y$ and $h=x+y+1$? Then $f$ is given by

$f(x,y) = (x+y, x+y+1)$.

That's not surjective, hence not finite. And it is even injective.

Comment: In my conditions, the only point that sent to 0 is 0. Does this change things?

Comment: @Z.A.Z.Z Maybe. If your function is not surjective, it is not finite. If your function however is surjective, and the fibre over $0$ is precisely one point, then it might even be bijective. If your  morphism is bijective, then it is an isomorphism by Zariski's Main Theorem, in which case you would be asking "are automorphisms finite morphisms?". The answer to that is "yes". However, is your morphism non-injective?

Comment: Yeah, it maybe non-injective

Comment: There seems to be a typo in the formula for $f$. As written, $f$ factors through $\mathbb{A^1}$ so it can't be quasi-finite.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bA}{\mathbb{A}}\newcommand{\bC}{\mathbb{C}}$Take $n=2, f:\bA^2_{\bC}\to\bA^2_{\bC}$ defined by $$f(x, y)=(x(1+xy),y)$$

For a point $(a, b)\in \bA^2(\bC)$ the preimage $f^{-1}(a, b)$ consists of one point if $b=0$ or $1+4ab=0$ and it has two points in all other cases. So $f$ is quasi-finite, but it is not proper: the limit of $f(1/t,-t)$ as $t$ tends to $0$ exists. Hence $f$ isn't finite.

This example appears e.g. as Example 23 in [The set of points at which the polynomial mapping is not proper, by Z. Jelonek](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/apm/apm58/apm5834.pdf). I've learned about it through a startling excercise (Problem 3 here http://achinger.impan.pl/rigid/ps10a.pdf) from a course by Piotr Achinger.